# Python Hex to Byte conversion producing ambiguous results

Tags: python, type-conversion, hex, byte

I am providing a snippet of my python code where I need to convert commands written in HEX to be converted in Bytes so that they can be sent over serial. However for some values of HEX, I am getting ambiguous conversion. Normally the following:

```
command = '0200C00903C9'
print (bytes.fromhex(command)
```

gives output:

```
output: b'\x02\x00\xc0\t\x03\xc9'
```

However, the below gives ambiguous results:

```
c_1 = '02030002'
c_2 = '03062000'
c_3 = '01110334'
command = c_1 + c_2 + c_3
print(bytes.fromhex(command))
```

gives:

```
output: b'\x02\x03\x00\x02\x03\x06 \x00\x01\x11\x034'
```

Ignore the space in between which corresponds to SPACE (ASCII Code: 20). But the output should be of the form:

```
output: b'\x02\x03\x00\x02\x03\x06 \x00\x01\x11\x03\x34'
```

weirdly enough, if I do:

```
c_1 = '02030002'
c_2 = '03062000'
c_3 = '0111033434'
command = c_1 + c_2 + c_3
print(bytes.fromhex(command))
```

It again gives an ambiguous conversion:

```
output: b'\x02\x03\x00\x02\x03\x06 \x00\x01\x11\x0344'
```

This trend continues. Why is it missing the 3's after '03'?

Comment: Kinda weird `bytes.fromhex('33')` => `b'3'`

Comment: hex 33 is [ascii character](http://www.asciitable.com/) 3 .?

Comment: Do you think this is a bug in bytes.fromhex() function?

Comment: I have got it! The HEX for number 3 is 33 in ASCII. So that's why it shows it as a single 3. This was really a little mind boggling.

Comment: You got it almost right. It's the fours that are not escaped, since `4` is a printable ascii character. `b'\x34\x34' == b'44'`

Comment: Byte code '34' corresponds to ASCII digit '4' so that's why it turns b'\x34' to 4.